# Unable to print using a class

Tags: python, oop

for the simplest code

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, color, height, breed):
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.breed = breed

        my_dog = Kolin(color='brown', height='1 feet', breed='german shephered')
        print(type(my_dog))
        print(my_dog.color)
```

Process finished with exit code 0 and nothing is printed
Note: it is on selenium python setup

Comment: Have you created your `Dog` object? Like this `dog = Dog('red', 56, 'german')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place your procedural code outside of the class. When using class to create an object you must use class name (`Dog`). I'm not really sure why you used `Kolin` in your code`.

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, color, height, breed):
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.breed = breed

my_dog = Dog(color='brown', height='1 feet', breed='german shephered')
print(type(my_dog))
print(my_dog.color)
```

Comment: Oh thats Amazing. Never thought of error due to spaces. as i always worked on Java. Thanksalot!

Comment: @swtt123 While whitespace is important in Python the other issue, where you tried using `kolin` (??) to initialize is a far bigger issue. I think you need to read up on how Object oriented programming in python works, and possibly even OOP in general.

Comment: I think he probably wanted to set dogs name to be `Kolin`. For that you must add another attribute like `name` to your class and use it as you would use `color` and other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The python statement `class` defines a class. At the end of running your script you will have a class defined in the local variables:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(locals())
```

Output:

```
{'Dog': <class __main__.Dog at 0x033966F8>,
 '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__file__': 'C:/Users/********/.PyCharm2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_7.py',
 '__name__': '__main__',
 '__package__': None,
 'pprint': <function pprint at 0x03430CF0>}
```

If you add another line to your script to execute you can see the class you've defined:

```
print(Dog)
```

Output:

```
__main__.Dog
```

You probably want to instantiate this class:

```
my_dog = Dog(color='brown', height='1 feet', breed='German Shepard')

print(type(my_dog))
print(my_dog.color)
```

It looks like you wanted to name your dog Kolin. You would need another attribute for this.